# randomly sample group to get a balanced group

Tags: r

Here is my dataframe:

```
data<- 
 ID     Group    Modules
 1      Male      Physics
 1      Male      Chemistry
 2      Female    Biology
 2      Female    Physics
 2      Female    Chemistry
 3      Male      Physics
 3      Male      Biology
 3      Male      Chemistry
 4      Male      Physics
 4      Male      Biology
 4      Male      Chemistry
 5      Male      Physics
 5      Male      Biology
 5      Male      Chemistry
 6      Male      Physics
 6      Male      Biology
 6      Male      Chemistry
 7      Female    Physics
 7      Female    Biology
 8      Female    Chemistry
 8      Male      Physics
 8      Male      Biology
 9      Male      Chemistry
 9      Male      Physics
 10      Male      Biology
 10      Male      Chemistry
 10      Male      Physics
 11      Male      Biology
 11      Male      Chemistry
 11      Male      Physics
 12      Female    Biology
 12      Female    Chemistry
```

The above data has more males (n=9) than females (n=3). I want to randomly select 3 males without replcaement, so I will end up with 3 males and 3 females.
I want to also retain the duplicate IDs, so my desried result will be:

```
newdata<- 
 ID     Group    Modules
 1      Male      Physics
 1      Male      Chemistry
 2      Female    Biology
 2      Female    Physics
 2      Female    Chemistry
 3      Male      Physics
 3      Male      Biology
 3      Male      Chemistry
 7      Female    Physics
 7      Female    Biology
 7      Female    Chemistry
 12     Female    Physics
 12     Female    Biology
 6      Male      Physics
 6      Male      Biology
 6      Male      Chemistry
```

Here is my code below:

```
samples_per_group<-6

new data<-data%>% group_by(Group)%>%slice(sample(n(),min(sampples_per_group, n())))%>%ungroup()
```

When I tried running this, it selects the 6 sample size (3 per group), however it only takes one row from each participant instead of returning all the rows for that participant. Basically, I want to select 3 ids on each group regardless of number of times that id is repeated. Any assistance will be welcome. Thank you

Comment: Please don't put `data<-` before text that isn't valid syntax ;) `dput(data)` is a nice way to make copy/pasteable data objects in valid R code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sample IDs, you need to get the IDs and sample them:

```
groups = data %>%
  distinct(ID, Group) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(group_size = n())

smallest_group = min(groups$group_size)

groups %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  sample_n(size = smallest_group) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  left_join(data)
```

Something like the above should work. It's difficult to get a single number *across* groups within a `dplyr` chain--doable--but I think it's cleaner to just break the pipeline and pull the number. We sample 3 (or however many) IDs by group, and then join back to the main data to get all the rows corresponding to those IDs.

Comment: Hi Gregor, thank you for your response. I tried the code, but got this: Error: `size` must be less or equal than 1 (size of data), set `replace` = TRUE to use sampling with replacement.